# JavaScript / REST - Build tabs after tab div elements have been created

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, tabs

I'm creating tabs using this code: http://akrabat.com/dynamic-javascript-tabs/
It basically creates tabs based on the amount of 'tab-content' divs in the 'tab-container'.
In my project I'm creating the 'tab-content' divs dynamically based on data retrieved from a XMLHttpRequest:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var doSomethingAJAX = function (el, url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.onload = function () { 

            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var tasks = data.data;
            var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("A");

            for(var h = 0; h < tasks.length; h++){

                var tabContainer = document.getElementById("tab-container");

                var divElement = document.createElement("div");
                divElement.className = 'tab-content';

                tabContainer.appendChild(divElement);

                var hOneElement = document.createElement("h1");
                hOneElement.className = 'tab';
                hOneElement.setAttribute('title', 'task' + h);
                hOneElement.innerHTML = tasks[h].name;

                divElement.appendChild(hOneElement);

                var formElement = document.createElement("form");
                formElement.className = 'taskForm';
                formElement.setAttribute('action', 'CompleteTask');
                formElement.setAttribute('method', 'post');

                divElement.appendChild(formElement);

                var taskId = tasks[h].id

                getFormProperties(taskId, h);

            }

        };
        xhr.onerror = function () { alert("error") };
        xhr.send();
    };
```

The divs get created exactly how I want them to but the tabs don't get built. The script that creates the tabs stops at this point:

```
tabContents = getChildElementsByClassName(tabContainer, 'tab-content');
    if(tabContents.length == 0)
        return;
```

I presume that it may be something with the ajax. How do I make sure the BuildTabs() function doesnt call until all the divs have been created?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/apitest.js"></script>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "css/tabs.css";</style>
<title>Tabs and REST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='tab-container'>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: I should also add that the getFormProperties() function also contains an XMLHttpRequest. In case that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this method;

```
 xhr.onload = function () { 

        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var tasks = data.data;
        var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("A");

        for(var h = 0; h < tasks.length; h++){

            var tabContainer = document.getElementById("tab-container");

            var divElement = document.createElement("div");
            divElement.className = 'tab-content';

            tabContainer.appendChild(divElement);

            var hOneElement = document.createElement("h1");
            hOneElement.className = 'tab';
            hOneElement.setAttribute('title', 'task' + h);
            hOneElement.innerHTML = tasks[h].name;

            divElement.appendChild(hOneElement);

            var formElement = document.createElement("form");
            formElement.className = 'taskForm';
            formElement.setAttribute('action', 'CompleteTask');
            formElement.setAttribute('method', 'post');

            divElement.appendChild(formElement);

            var taskId = tasks[h].id

            getFormProperties(taskId, h);

        }
       BuildTabs();
    };
```

Comment: What does this do exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry now I see that you used onload method,
in each case after completion of the for loop (var x = 0; x <tasks.length; h ++)
Set the function to create tabs  BuildTabs()

Comment: It almost worked except for a slight bug (which was more to do with another part of my code) so I set the BuildTabs() after the loop and now it works. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.